# "Das ist das Haus vom Nikolaus" and Euler cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the following graph $(V,E)$:

[image: Das ist das Haus vom Ni-ko-laus]

With $a, b, c, d, e \in V$. Then I obviously can make an Euler cycle: $[b, a, c, e, d , c, b, e, a]$. But it also holds that $deg(a)=deg(b)=3$ which is not even, which implies that there can not exist an Euler cycle. What am I missing?

Comment: It's not a cycle, since it starts in $a$ and ends in $b$ (note that these two are the odd vertices, as it should be).

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thanks for you answer :).

Comment: das=ae, ist=ed, das=dc, Haus=cb, vom=ba, Ni=ac, ko=ce, laus=eb.